# Why images and CSS do not show under HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

I just added an SSL to my site. When I go to https://mydomain.com I see the text but no CSS or images are there. It is on a dedicated server and I have a full control of the code.

All paths currently are relative. I can view images and css when I go to those files directly whether using HTTP or HTTPS. But when i load a page they are not loading...

When I use Firebug and look in NET, I see for each image 302 Found. What does that mean?

What changes do I need to make to make sure http and https display site similarly?

Do I make all paths absolute? Is there a way to make a single change to affect all or I actually have to go and change each and every one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have hotlink protection? If you have try to disable it. And see if it helps.

Comment: Instead of disabling it you could write (in your htaccess) something like this : RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.com

Comment: What is hotlink protection?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make everything absolute, but you need to make sure that your CSS and images are accessible over SSL. Try accessing them directly, or use Firebug or a similar browser tool to figure out where it's trying to load them from. Consider using "Protocol-relative URLs" so that CSS, images, and such are always accessed using the same protocol (http or https) as the page itself. http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: I can see my images and CSS with both HTTP and HTTPS but obviously they do not load. Also when I go to my HTTPS page and view source in FF and then click on a CSS link it takes me to HTTP... But if I click on a link, while on HTTPS page it loads another page as HTTPS. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pointing at your CSS with an absolute link (like `http://www.yourcompany.net/yourcompany.css`) it will not show the CSS in https. If you make that absolute `https://www.yourcompany.net/yourcompany.css`, it will work in both calls.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If page is opened in https then css/js should also be loaded in https. By this I mean, to load css/js it should use the same protocol as it used for opening html/jsp/jsf etc page. So the solution is to not use absolute url for css/js. Use relative url instead like this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
```

OR use this :

```
<% String contextPath=request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()"+":"+request.getServerPort()+request.getContextPath();
```

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<%=contextPath>/css/style.css" />`

This should solve image loading issue.

Comment: You can use a double forward slash to indicate absolute but with same protocol: such as "//css/myfile.css".